# Authorization issue when downloading AMZ Advertising Report

Tags: node.js, api, express, authentication

I have the following app to download productAds from amazons Sponsored Products API

Docs:  https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/reference/reports

When I try to fun it, I get the response from requesting the report, and obtain a file in an s3 Bucket.

```
server is running at localhost:3000
{"reportId":"amzn1.clicPI.v1.p7.5B7EE.d141f-e5-4b-a8-6a4e712","status":"SUCCESS","statusDetails":"Report has been successfully generated","location":"https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v1/reports/amzn1.clsAPI.v1.p7.5B7EE.d151f-e5-4b-a8-699e712/download","fileSize":22}
```

Next I try to download the report 
[image]

and the repose I get the following erro:

```
donwloading <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified</Message><ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>bearer Atza|IwEBIJvCt20TUi122srkN4JCOdUxlBNuLJBrtbIGF9x5QbKG67f-K-0L4RkLzeyouXWy_U_-VscaCe1aFqOJK55X9Mu2X6nwWkAWRyhc6cCMfPjKpyyVjKtPqC8Plme84om1dqtmIqC93yUVc_clHimQqmnl262te2EXyUhYoVQg8hK2nlDG67Iw7xjsLK4rgl3E4RR36DHnZkEOnVQZtfjIkIbcYtsCSAdpRZRazF4FQfpS-jHvMlwuH8TZfY9tRpmBEx5fjJw1WZ14Dejqti23mZ7yt-MjNkUuD-DdPXs3fek1ZJePlHEVzcI2y_WzCnwJnoSVp5a5w1WgNco8YqEGEuLsT9S0dxQRluTiw8f4b4lx2FFFm9jz0K7pqo1Mvs6DZOVCDJzE-xJ_VLlWoE5QDMUAMor4AEQH44_0NWBjJDrYaVvn1vZLCER1uxW4jgr127W5yXaj4y1vj_vADwFq9a3330hAc73EWwL6FFSfoTQZyNc4Fh1d3DXfVHpXFk6cv0bHt4cV_OotGwGHat5fv75VHX5K3al3Xd5-QJv2cTiQ9srY5oqKsdbxptGaxAdrdMQaUlFHhyHEGbwED9xYoCw6-IauN15gvMAei9wz2kzRCA</ArgumentValue><RequestId>BDCE812C4363E9D2</RequestId><HostId>4ixH24mPtMBt+FDnI3rM9UJP95toaNBmmR1v0uQJ5XkyiXbtLEuZ8d+vDI0+gquwhn6/Fkz6/+o=</HostId></Error>
```

Here is the app. How can I download the report and pass the headers correctly? I found this repo in PHP that has the download function: https://github.com/dbrent-amazon/amazon-advertising-api-php/blob/master/AmazonAdvertisingApi/Client.php

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const request = require('request');
const moment = require('moment');
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const config = require('./config')
const auth = require('./helpers/auth');
const cron = require('./helpers/cron');
const con = require('./helpers/database');

const getProfiles = (headers) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            url: config.ad_url + '/v1/profiles',
            method: "GET",
            headers: headers
        }, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(body);
        });
    })
}

const createReport = (params, recordType, headers) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            url: config.ad_url + '/v1/' + recordType + '/report',
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers,
            json: params
        }, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(body);
        });
    })
}

const getReport = (reportId, headers) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            url: config.ad_url + '/v1/reports/' + reportId,
            method: "GET",
            headers: headers
        }, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(body);
        });
    })
}

function download(fileUrl, apiPath, callback) {
    var url = require('url'),
        http = require('http'),
        p = url.parse(fileUrl),
        timeout = 10000;

    var file = fs.createWriteStream(apiPath);

    var timeout_wrapper = function (req) {
        return function () {
            console.log('abort');
            req.abort();
            callback("File transfer timeout!");
        };
    };


    console.log('before');

    var request = http.get(fileUrl).on('response', function (res) {
        console.log('in cb');
        var len = parseInt(res.headers['content-length'], 10);
        var downloaded = 0;

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            file.write(chunk);
            downloaded += chunk.length;
            process.stdout.write("Downloading " + (100.0 * downloaded / len).toFixed(2) + "% " + downloaded + " bytes" + isWin ? "\033[0G" : "\r");
            // reset timeout
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = setTimeout(fn, timeout);
        }).on('end', function () {
            // clear timeout
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            file.end();
            console.log(file_name + ' downloaded to: ' + apiPath);
            callback(null);
        }).on('error', function (err) {
            // clear timeout
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            callback(err.message);
        });
    });

    // generate timeout handler
    var fn = timeout_wrapper(request);

    // set initial timeout
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(fn, timeout);
}

const recordType = 'productAds';
const campaignType = 'sponsoredProducts';
const reportDate = moment().format('YYYYMMDD');
const metrics = 'campaignId,sku,currency,attributedConversions1d';

const reportParam = {
    campaignType: campaignType,  
    // segment: "query",
    reportDate: reportDate,      
    metrics: metrics             
}


auth().then(res => {
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': config.token_type + ' ' + res.access_token,
        'Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope': '196354651614',
    }

    // getProfiles(headers).then(res => {})
    const reportId = 'amzn1.clicksAI.1.p.5B057EE.d41f-e5-4a-a8-699e712';
        getReport(reportId, headers).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            const file = JSON.parse(res);
            // console.log(file.location )
            // download

            request({
                url: file.location,
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': headers.Authorization,
                    'Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope': '196335474',
                    'Allow': 'GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE'
                }
            }, (err, response, body) => {
                console.log('donwloading', body)
            })
        })

    createReport(reportParam, recordType, headers).then(res => {
        const reportId = 'amzn1.clicksI.v1.p7.5B07EE.d1541f-e5-eb-a68-6996e712';
    })
})


app.listen(3000, function(err) {
    console.log("server is running at localhost:3000");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by sending the "Authorization" header to S3 and it doesn't want that. The reason is because the /download response from the API is a 307 redirect so the client you are using is redirecting with full API headers. To get around this, prevent your client from following redirects and parse the S3 location from the header of the response instead.

Comment: How to download report using java

Comment: Is there any Java SDK available, I am getting issue while trying to download as REST  - Thank you